# Complicated Converting Row into Column Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I got these code:

```
String[] s1={"Samsung Smarphone","20MB"};
            String[] s11={"Apple Smarphone","25MB"};

            String[] s2={"Samsung Smarphone","3 in"};
            String[] s22={"Apple Smarphone","6 in"};

            String[] s3={"Samsung Smarphone","3GB"};
            String[] s33={"Apple Smarphone","2 GB"};




            String[] s4={"Apple Smarphone","iphone1"};
            String[] s44={"Apple Smarphone","iphone2"};
            String[] s444={"Apple Smarphone","iphone3"};

            List<String[]> l1=new ArrayList<String[]>();
            l1.add(s1);
            l1.add(s11);

            List<String[]> l2=new ArrayList<String[]>();
            l2.add(s2);
            l2.add(s22);

            List<String[]> l3=new ArrayList<String[]>();
            l3.add(s3);
            l3.add(s33);

            List<String[]> l4=new ArrayList<String[]>();
            l4.add(s4);
            l4.add(s44);
            l4.add(s444);

            Vector<List<String[]>> myV=new Vector<List<String[]>>();
            myV.add(l1);
            myV.add(l2);
            myV.add(l3);
            myV.add(l4);


            List<String[]> resultL=new ArrayList<String[]>();


            String[] mainS={"Samsung Smarphone","Apple Smarphone","Apple Smarphone","Apple Smarphone"};
            for (int i=0; i<mainS.length; i++){


                String[] theRow=new String[myV.size()+1];

                for (int k=0; k<myV.size(); k++){
                    List<String[]> smallList=(List<String[]>)myV.elementAt(k);
                    String[][] small2DArr=new String[smallList.size()][2];
                    smallList.toArray(small2DArr);

                    String strMain=mainS[i];
                    int rows=small2DArr.length;



                    int cols=2;

                    for( int y=0; y<rows; y++)
                    {
                        for(int z=0; z<cols; z++){
                            String str=small2DArr[y][z];
                            if(strMain.equals(str))
                            {
                                theRow[0]=strMain;
                                theRow[k+1]=small2DArr[y][1];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                resultL.add(theRow);
            }

            for(int u=0; u<resultL.size(); u++)
            {
                String[] myR=resultL.get(u);
                //int ddd=xxx.length;
                System.out.println("\n----------------\n");
                for (String s : myR)
                {
                    System.out.print(s +"\t");
                }

            }
```

The result is:

```
Samsung Smarphone   20MB    3 in    3GB null    
----------------

Apple Smarphone 25MB    6 in    2 GB    iphone3 
----------------

Apple Smarphone 25MB    6 in    2 GB    iphone3 
----------------

Apple Smarphone 25MB    6 in    2 GB    iphone3
```

The above result is not correct. I want the result like this:

```
Samsung Smarphone   20MB    3 in    3GB null    
----------------

Apple Smarphone 25MB    6 in    2 GB    iphone1 
----------------

Apple Smarphone 25MB    6 in    2 GB    iphone2 
----------------

Apple Smarphone 25MB    6 in    2 GB    iphone3
```

Could you help me to fix?

Comment: Before posting here , Have you tried to test it in debug mode ??

Comment: Is the used data structure mandatory or can you change it freely?

Comment: The result of what? How did you print the output you provided? Could you show the corresponding code snippet?

Comment: If I understand what you are doing I have to say that this is one of the worst codes I've ever seen

Comment: @ iberbeu
You are using "Ad hominem" fallacy. "Ad hominem" is an argument made personally against an opponent instead of against their argument. (wiki)

if u say it worat you gotta argue why it's worst rather than just saying just for saying without any evidence?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is with the equal check, `if(strMain.equals(str))`. As all the three smartphone represents same company name, you get the wrong value (whichever comes first).

For this kind of problem it is better not to check based on the company name (here apple smartphone). Think how you would design a database. 

If you design a database for the same representation, you would never use the company name as your primary key right? Because one company can have multiple phones in the market.

My suggestion use a bean instead of plain string. The bean contains the company name and an id. override the equals method of the bean. Something like below,

```
class MyBean{
        private String company;
        private int id;
        public MyBean(int id, String company) {
            this.id = id;
            this.company = company;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return id == ((MyBean)obj).id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return company;
        }
    }
```

This is just an example. You can follow your own algorithm for equalization.